# Trying to match a string in the format of domain\username using Lua and then mask the pattern with '#'

Tags: regex, lua, lua-patterns

I am trying to match a string in the format of domain\username using Lua and then mask the pattern with `#`.

So if the input is `sample.com\admin;` the output should be `######.###\#####;`. The string can end with either a `;`, `,`, `.` or whitespace.

More examples:

```
sample.net\user1,hello   ->   ######.###\#####,hello
test.org\testuser. Next  ->   ####.###\########. Next
```

I tried `([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)\.?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)\b` which works perfectly with http://regexr.com/. But with Lua demo it doesn't. What is wrong with the pattern?

Below is the code I used to check in Lua:

```
test_text="I have the 123 name as domain.com\admin as 172.19.202.52 the credentials"
pattern="([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.-]+).?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)\b"
res=string.match(test_text,pattern)
print (res)
```

It is printing `nil`.

Comment: lua doesn't support regular expressions. lua uses [patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1). If you need regular expressions you need a library for them.

Comment: you may want to consider using [lpeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like already mentioned pure Lua does not have regex, only patterns.
Your regex however can be matched with the following code and pattern:

```
--[[
sample.net\user1,hello   ->   ######.###\#####,hello
test.org\testuser. Next  ->   ####.###\########. Next
]]

s1 = [[sample.net\user1,hello]]
s2 = [[test.org\testuser. Next]]
s3 = [[abc.domain.org\user1]]

function mask_domain(s)
  s = s:gsub('(%a[%a%d%.%-]-)%.?([%a%d]+)\\([%a%d]+)([%;%,%.%s]?)',
      function(a,b,c,d)
        return ('#'):rep(#a)..'.'..('#'):rep(#b)..'\\'..('#'):rep(#c)..d
      end)
  return s
end

print(s1,'=>',mask_domain(s1))
print(s2,'=>',mask_domain(s2))
print(s3,'=>',mask_domain(s3))
```

The last example does not end with ; , . or whitespace.  If it must follow this, then simply remove the final ? from pattern.

UPDATE: If in the domain (e.g. abc.domain.org) you need to also reveal any dots before that last one you can replace the above function with this one:

```
function mask_domain(s)
  s = s:gsub('(%a[%a%d%.%-]-)%.?([%a%d]+)\\([%a%d]+)([%;%,%.%s]?)',
      function(a,b,c,d)
        a = a:gsub('[^%.]','#')
        return a..'.'..('#'):rep(#b)..'\\'..('#'):rep(#c)..d
      end)
  return s
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Lua pattern isn't regular expression, that's why your regex doesn't work.

- `\b` isn't supported, you can use the more powerful `%f` frontier pattern if needed.
- In the string `test_text`, `\` isn't escaped, so it's interpreted as `\a`.
- `.` is a magic character in patterns, it needs to be escaped.

This code isn't exactly equivalent to your pattern, you can tweek it if needed:

```
test_text = "I have the 123 name as domain.com\\admin as 172.19.202.52 the credentials"
pattern = "(%a%w+)%.?(%w+)\\([%w]+)"
print(string.match(test_text,pattern))
```

Output: `domain com admin`

---

After fixing the pattern, the task of replacing them with `#` is easy, you might need `string.sub` or `string.gsub`.

Comment: It doesn't get the domain name properly for abc.domain.org\user1, it gives only domain org user1 as the output